# How use abstract constructor for game objects?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, prototype

Please help fix my code. In my game exists enemies objects and player object. They have the same properties: xCoord, yCoord. I'm trying to inherit these properties from the abstract constructor Ship():

```
var player,
    enemies = [],
    enemiesCntInit = 10;

function Ship(x, y) {
  this.xCoord = x;
  this.yCoord = y;
};

function PlayerShip(x, y) {
  this.petrol = 100;
};  

function EnemyShip(x, y) {  
  this.color = 'red';
}; 

PlayerShip.prototype = Object.create(Ship.prototype);


player = new PlayerShip(100, 100); 

for(var i = 0; i < enemiesCntInit; i++) {
  enemies.push(new EnemyShip(0, 0));
}

console.log(player);
console.log(enemies);
```

But all objects do not have properties: xCoords, yCoords

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5va8rtbk/8/)

Comment: You're never calling the constructor in `Ship` - its by no means automagic. Inheritance i n vanilla javascript is not like you expect. Try reading this for some context: http://markdalgleish.com/2012/10/a-touch-of-class-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: One thing to keep in mind... JS doesn't really support inheritance. At least, not the way you're used to if coming from Java or C# or most other object oriented languages. You'll need to carefully rethink your paradigms, or consider a JS super-set language like TypeScript which can implement these kinds of paradigms for you. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `call` method and pass your `parameters` inside the `PlayerShip` function.

```
Ship.call(this, x,y);
```

Calling the `parent's` **constructor** initializes the object itself, this is done with every instantiation (you can pass different parameters each time you construct it).

```js
var player,
    enemies = [],
    enemiesCntInit = 10;

function Ship(x, y) {
  this.xCoord = x;
  this.yCoord = y;
};

function PlayerShip(x, y) {
  Ship.call(this, x,y);
  this.petrol = 100;
};  

function EnemyShip(x, y) {  
  Ship.call(this, x,y);
  this.color = 'red';
}; 

PlayerShip.prototype = Object.create(Ship.prototype);


player = new PlayerShip(100, 100); 

for(var i = 0; i < enemiesCntInit; i++) {
  enemies.push(new EnemyShip(0, 0));
}

console.log(player);
console.log(enemies);
```

Comment: but i need create player and enemies. 2 type of objects

Comment: @provoter33, yes, invoke same function within `PlayerShip` method.